# What's the accurate dataset for text classification of tntsearch package

Tags: php, machine-learning, dataset, text-classification

I have found a package for text classification in PHP in which the method for the classifier accepts the sentence and the category like this:

```
$classifier->learn('that was a clean election', 'not sports');
$classifier->learn('that was a nice game','sports');

$classifier->guess('the game was bad');
// returns sports
```

What dataset is best for this approach? 
And also I have a dynamic category which means I can add additional category. My problem is I have to give examples in every category added, which means I need more data in this category.

Answer (score 0):

> There are a lot of datasets for this purpose, [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01710.pdf) there
>   is detailed Information about the Major ones, I linked in the following:

- [DBpediaOntologyClassiﬁcation](https://textminingonline.com/tag/dbpedia-ontology-classification-dataset)
- [AmazonReviewSentimentAnalysis](https://www.kaggle.com/bittlingmayer/amazonreviews)
- [Yahoo! AnswersTopicClassiﬁcation](https://www.kaggle.com/c/stat-441841-data-challenge-ii/data)
- [AG News Categorization in English](http://www.di.unipi.it/~gulli/AG_corpus_of_news_articles.html)

Comment: What about the dynamic category ? I mean at first I have to create a static category and all the data within it . Then now in my live system , an admin wants to add another category, now I want my system to automatically adopt the newly added categories and just use the dataset that is currently being used. Thank you